# Finite structural Ramsey degrees

Tags: combinatorics, dynamical-systems, model-theory, ramsey-theory

I have been trying to acclimate myself with finite Ramsey degrees in structural Ramsey theory, my resource being Zucker's *TOPOLOGICAL DYNAMICS OF AUTOMORPHISM GROUPS,
ULTRAFILTER COMBINATORICS,
AND THE GENERIC POINT PROBLEM* ([https://www.math.cmu.edu/~andrewz/GPP.pdf](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eandrewz/GPP.pdf)).  Specifically, I have been trying to understand the claim (Proposition 5.8) that if an "excellent" expansion $K^*$ of a Fraisse class $K$ has the Ramsey property, then every element of $K$ has a finite Ramsey degree.

I find it hard, however, to understand the argument. The proof involves a decreasing chain of "thick" sets of embeddings.  The existence of a dense set is arguably guaranteed by Lemma 5.9, but I do not see how to guarantee the thick set constructed in each stage is included in the thick set obtained thus far.

What am I missing?  I also believe that there is a simpler argument if you assume that each member of $K^*$ is rigid (Zucker does not make this assumption).

Comment: The assumption that $K^*$ has the Ramsey property implies that every structure in $K^*$ is rigid. Can you be more precise about what it is you don't understand in the proof? Is Lemma 4.2 useful here?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for your point on rigidity.  What I didn't understand was how to construct a thick set Ti+1 that is contained in Ti as on line 1 of page 16 (of the Web version).  I didn't know how to ensure the inclusion by using Proposition 4.1.3.  But I think I understand the argument now: one uses Proposition 4.1.4 instead.

Comment: Yes, that looks right to me.